# Tips for a faster website

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, optimization

I would like to know if there are any tips and tricks for my site to load faster?

For example in my site I have 4 groups of background images that switch when hover..
is there a way to load them before? 
is there a jquery plugin for that?

If I echo in php a div with all the images that are in my site with display none before the DOCTYPE. will it help?
and general tips in for html/css/jquery?
All suggestions are welcome...

Thank you.

Comment: If you really want a faster website, simplify it down. Don't add many kilobytes of js. Output some nicely formatted HTML code. The less a browser has to do, the quicker it will be. The less data that a user has to download, the faster it will be. Your answer is in writing clean efficient code - not resorting to crutches and bandaids. Pre-loading images isn't a bad idea, but it probably won't solve a badly designed website.

Comment: what about http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/speed/tools

Answer (score 4):

Your image loading can be made a lot faster with **[Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)**.
Using that will just need you to join your images up. The [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) can help you with that.

If you want to give the illusion of your background loading all at once, try using [**interlaced**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_%28bitmaps%29) PNGs.

Comment: thank you for your help!
if I have a couple of middle size images(background for the site), is it better to have a one big sprite image?

Comment: It will speed up switching between backgrounds, if you use sprites. So, though the initial load time might be slightly higher, your subsequent load times will be low.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find some very good tips here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/

and especially here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some things you can do.

- Reduce the number of requests. You can make [sprites](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS-Sprites) and put all images together.
- Use APC and other caching mechanisms
- Use [memcache](http://memcached.org/)
- Apache caching module
- And you could use [modpagespeed](http://memcached.org/) from Google. And makes the most things of them.

But i think the best way is to have a good programmed website with a good structure. Then means don't load to much classes only classes you need and many more. Here you can look at **design patterns**.

Answer (score 0):

An interactive way of understanding this would be to use the Y-Slow extension to the Firebug addon on firefox. This addon will assess your current website and give you proper tips for improvement with regards to CSS, compression etc.

Answer (score 0):

## PageSpeed Insights for Chrome

If you download the plugin for Google Chrome, it list these facts that help make a website faster.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/using_chrome

Avoid CSS @import

  Using CSS @import in an external stylesheet can add additional delays during the loading of a web page.

Avoid a character set in the meta tag

Avoid bad requests

Combine images into CSS sprites

Defer parsing of JavaScript

Enable Keep-Alive

Enable compression

Inline Small CSS

Inline Small JavaScript

Leverage browser caching

Make landing page redirects cacheable

Minify CSS

Minify HTML

Minimize redirects

Minimize request size

Optimize images

Optimize the order of styles and scripts

Prefer asynchronous resources

Put CSS in the document head

Remove query strings from static resources

Serve resources from a consistent URL

Serve scaled images

Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header

Specify a cache validator

Specify a character set

Specify image dimensions

Comment: Nice uncredited copy/paste with the explanations removed (some of that advice is very bad without the additional commentary).

Comment: @Quentin  I was editing it while you made this assertion. i bet you were the one who downvoted it too. after it only being published for 10 seconds.